# How to create a checkbox in Valor ngx-bootstrap tab heading?

Tags: angular, tabs, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a checkbox inside of the Tab-heading elements. The element is created but the checkbox (cick) is never called but the Tab is changed.

Please see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsaf63?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html for demonstration (the demo is working but not showing the correct CSS. Please see the console for the output).

My questions are now: how is it possible to realise a checkbox inside the heading but NOT changing the tab when clicking the checkbox.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `click` event and stopping event propagation

**component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked[i]" 
(ngModelChange)="onSelectResult(entry)" 
(click)="onCheckboxChanged($event)" />  <!--  <===== add this -->
```

**component.ts**

```
onCheckboxChanged(evt)
{
 evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

[Modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqot8p?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Glad I could help!